# Use gcc in Xcode 4.6

Tags: c, xcode, gcc

For my CPS classes this semester we are transitioning from C++ down to C. For my C++ I grew attached to xCode and it's quick and easy debugger. However, for C, xCode is letting me do a lot of stuff C++ that I shouldn't be allowed to do in C.

For example, I can initialize and declare a loop variable from within a loop, which is not allowed in C.

C:

```
int i
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
     printf("This is a number: %i", i);
}
```

But IS allowed in C++
C++:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
     printf("This is a number: %i", i);
}
```

All my work has to be compiled on a lab machine (running linux and compiling with gcc) in order for it to count, so I am looking for a way to continue using xCode to run my programs with gcc (or at least something that won't let me do C++ stuff). It seems xCode has dropped gcc support. Is there anyway I can continue to use xCode but have it compile in an "old-school" school way so it will catch things like this?

For now I have been using sublime2 and just compiling in the terminal. Which is fine for now, but when it comes to debugging I have developed a hatred for gdb after using xCode for so long.

Comment: Declaring `i` inside the loop has been legal in C since [the C99 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99).

Comment: @KurtRevis, Thats what I was afraid of, we must be stuck using an old version of C standard on our lab machines. Somehow gcc doesn't like this. I'll just have to jump between the two and figure out the differences as I go. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Unless your lab machines are truly ancient, you can invoke gcc on them with '-std=c99' (or '-std=gnu99' for C99 with GNU extensions). If you're not sure whether your class allows this, talk to your instructor. Maybe he'll be happy with it already, or maybe you can make the case that it's about time to start using the 14 year old version of the language instead of the 24 year old one. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can [tell clang what dialect of C to use](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#c) using the `-std` argument to the compiler. It sounds like you may want `-std=c89` or `-std=gnu89`.

In Xcode, in the Build Settings for your project or target, set "C Language Dialect" to whatever you want.

I wouldn't count on this catching everything, but it should get you closer.